# Converting a column with as.Date

Tags: r, date, datetime, dataframe

There is following df:

> data$time

```
 [1] 2012-06 2012-07 2012-08 2012-09 2012-10 2012-11 2012-12 2013-01 2013-02 2013-03 2013-04 2013-05 2013-06 ...
```

> class(data$time)

```
[1] "factor"
```

I want to convert the column into date format:

> as.Date(data$time)

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

> as.Date(data$time, format = "%Y-%m")

doesn't work either:

```
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ... (Batman?)
```

How can I solve this? I need to prepare data$time as Date, so that I can load it into zoo(data).

Thank you!

Comment: Because date also include day.  You try `as.Date(paste0(data$time, "-01"))`

Comment: The second link was very helpful, though I didn't find it via search. Excuse me.